# Fatal error: Reading EnvironmentObject<AppStore> outside View.body: file only on iOS13 but no above

Tags: ios, swift, crash, swiftui, ios13

I am creating an app and I have to connect both SwiftUI & UIKit. Everything work fine on iOS above 13.0 but on 13.0 I have a crash with a message saying:

```
 Fatal error: Reading EnvironmentObject<AppStore> outside View.body: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-24.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Are there any differences between iOS 13 and iOS 13.1+?

This is my `UIViewControllerRepresentable` struct:

```
struct MyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MyViewController
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) -> MyViewController {
        let myViewController = MyViewController(store: store)

        return myViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) {}
}
```

This is my `UIViewController`:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @ObservedObject var store: AppStore

    init(store: AppStore) {
        self.store = store        
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```